# Text box and button not appearing in the steamlit app

Tags: python, streamlit, ifc, ifc-open-shell

Hello there i am using streamlit and ifcopenshell to create an app that processes IFC models. I hit a wall in the initial build up of this app. I am trying to output a text box and an apply button however when i run the code these entities don't appear. I would appreciate some direction in the code.

```
    import streamlit as st
    import ifcopenshell

    def callback_upload():
        st.session_state["is_file_upload"] = True
        st.session_state["ifc_file"] =   ifcopenshell.file.from_string(st.session_state["uploaded_file"].getvalue().decode("utf-8"))


    def main():      
        st.set_page_config(
            layout= "wide",
            page_title="IFC Stream",
            page_icon="✍️",
        )
        st.title("StreamLite IFC")
        st.markdown(
            """
            ### click on the browse file to begin
            """
         )
        uploaded_file = st.sidebar.file_uploader("choose a file", key="uploaded_file",on_change= callback_upload)

        if "is_file_uploaded" in st.session_state and st.session_state["is_file_uploaded"]:
            st.sidebar.success("file is loaded!")
            st.sidebar.write("you may now reload a new file")

            col1, col2 = st.columns (2)
            with col1:
                 project_name = st.session_state["ifc_file"].by_type("IfcProject")[0].Name
                 st.write(project_name)
       
            with col2:
                st.text_input("✍️", key="project_name_input")
                st.button("Apply", key="project_name_apply")
       
           
    if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quickly tried to re-run your code, and there is a typo in "`is_file_uploaded`":

```
def callback_upload():
    st.session_state["is_file_uploaded"] = True
    st.session_state["ifc_file"] = ifcopenshell.file.from_string(st.session_state["uploaded_file"].getvalue().decode("utf-8"))
```

However, as I did not manage to install a compatible version of `ifcopenshell`, I was not able to fully test (I don't get the `apply` button). I have another error afterwards but hopefully you won't have it.

[image]